# How can I find proper documentation for firebase realtime database and flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

So I recently shifted to realtime database from cloud firestore for my app's chat features, mostly because of how expensive cloud firestore can be on scale in terms of a chat app with multiple reads/writes.

The problem I'm facing is that there are no proper documentation or any sort of courses that I can take which will educate me on how to implement the realtime database with flutter. I'm struggling a lot with displaying the chat messages in the order of the time they were sent. With cloud firestore there was proper material that I could read and learn from. But this doesn't seem to be the case for realtime database and flutter.

This seems very weird, because if I am not wrong , RTDB was launched way before cloud firestore, so shouldn't there be more material for that , or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, real time database is much older than Firestore, but there aren't many resources and most of them are outdated, I wanted to shift for real time database for the exact same reason, a chat app, the best thing I could find is this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvvBxTUAZ78), it has everything you need to know and after watching I feel like real time database is much easier than Firestore, all you need to do add new item to the database is `.pus().set({})` and you're done, as for loading data you only need `FireBaseAnimatedList` and all the data comes sorted, since the random key that each new item generates comes with a time stamp, again every thing I needed was in that youtube video, so you don't need that much to learn it.

***Best of luck.***

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up learning it after all, by just coding a lot. Instead of using a Firebase Animated List I used a Stream Builder to load the chats and get the real time updates and then sorted the map I received in order of the timestamp, this worked like a charm.